# How can I make my flipable cards responsive? (CSS&HTML)

Tags: html, css

I have some flipable cards. I want that they align next to each other and when it doesn't fit it will go in a row under the other cards. I want 5 cards next to each, but to simplify it I have first 2 cards. Does anyone know how I can make them responsive? Must I do this with flex? If so, how? I think it's possible with flexbox.

```css
.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
.flip-card2 {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.flip-card2:hover .flip-card-inner2 {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front2, .flip-card-back2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front2 {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-card-back2 {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Card Flip with Text</h1>
<h3>Hover over the image below:</h3>

<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h1>John Doe</h1> 
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p> 
      <p>We love that guy</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flip-card2">
  <div class="flip-card-inner2">
    <div class="flip-card-front2">
      <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back2">
      <h1>John Doe</h1> 
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p> 
      <p>We love that guy</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: This is the picture I meant]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can also do it with flex as well. I have done it using display:grid which is really useful to use if you are having more than 4 boxes in columns. This is also fully responsive and will work on any device :)

You can use flex and it will solve the problem I guess but on a large screen, you may have only 4 boxes in columns.

```
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
```

```css
 .text {
  text-align: center;
}
.cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(275px, 1fr));
  gap: 10px;
  justify-items: center;
}

.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
.flip-card2 {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.flip-card2:hover .flip-card-inner2 {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front2,
.flip-card-back2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front2 {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-card-back2 {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
     <div class="text">
    <h1>Card Flip with Text</h1>
    <h3>Hover over the image below:</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="cards">
      <div class="flip-card">
        <div class="flip-card-inner">
          <div class="flip-card-front">
            <img
              src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png"
              alt="Avatar"
              style="width: 300px; height: 300px"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="flip-card-back">
            <h1>John Doe</h1>
            <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
            <p>We love that guy</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="flip-card">
        <div class="flip-card-inner">
          <div class="flip-card-front">
            <img
              src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png"
              alt="Avatar"
              style="width: 300px; height: 300px"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="flip-card-back">
            <h1>John Doe</h1>
            <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
            <p>We love that guy</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="flip-card">
        <div class="flip-card-inner">
          <div class="flip-card-front">
            <img
              src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png"
              alt="Avatar"
              style="width: 300px; height: 300px"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="flip-card-back">
            <h1>John Doe</h1>
            <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
            <p>We love that guy</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="flip-card">
        <div class="flip-card-inner">
          <div class="flip-card-front">
            <img
              src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png"
              alt="Avatar"
              style="width: 300px; height: 300px"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="flip-card-back">
            <h1>John Doe</h1>
            <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
            <p>We love that guy</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="flip-card">
        <div class="flip-card-inner">
          <div class="flip-card-front">
            <img
              src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png"
              alt="Avatar"
              style="width: 300px; height: 300px"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="flip-card-back">
            <h1>John Doe</h1>
            <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
            <p>We love that guy</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I need some help ;) When I make te screen size smaller, then there are 3 cards on row 1 and 2 cards on the second row. However these 2 cards are not divide evenly over the screen. What must I change in order to do that?

Comment: can you share SS because I did not get what exactly you want to do :) which 2 cards are not divided?

Comment: I have added a SS in my post. What I mean is that when my screen is a certain size and the first row has 3 cards, the second row has 2 cards, but those card are not centered.

Comment: Btw do you know how I can get the width excluding the vertical scrollbar? Because the gap of the left card is 10px and the gap for the right card too, but the scrollbar lays over it.

Comment: yes I know I got your point now! give me some moment I will do that and will update my ans :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243759/discussion-between-milan-sachani-and-majoranonymous).

Comment: Okay we will discuss there

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap all of your flip-cards in a container and apply flexBox on that container

```
.card-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```css
body{
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

.card-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 1100px;
  background-color: bisque;
}

.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  margin: 2rem;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
.flip-card2 {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.flip-card2:hover .flip-card-inner2 {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front2, .flip-card-back2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front2 {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-card-back2 {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<h1>Card Flip with Text</h1>
    <h3>Hover over the image below:</h3>
    <div class="card-container">
      <div class="flip-card">
        <div class="flip-card-inner">
          <div class="flip-card-front">
            <img
              src="img_avatar.png"
              alt="Avatar"
              style="width: 300px; height: 300px"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="flip-card-back">
            <h1>John Doe</h1>
            <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
            <p>We love that guy</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flip-card">
        <div class="flip-card-inner">
          <div class="flip-card-front">
            <img
              src="img_avatar.png"
              alt="Avatar"
              style="width: 300px; height: 300px"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="flip-card-back">
            <h1>John Doe</h1>
            <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
            <p>We love that guy</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flip-card">
        <div class="flip-card-inner">
          <div class="flip-card-front">
            <img
              src="img_avatar.png"
              alt="Avatar"
              style="width: 300px; height: 300px"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="flip-card-back">
            <h1>John Doe</h1>
            <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
            <p>We love that guy</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flip-card">
        <div class="flip-card-inner">
          <div class="flip-card-front">
            <img
              src="img_avatar.png"
              alt="Avatar"
              style="width: 300px; height: 300px"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="flip-card-back">
            <h1>John Doe</h1>
            <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
            <p>We love that guy</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flip-card flip-card2">
        <div class="flip-card-inner2">
          <div class="flip-card-front2">
            <img
              src="img_avatar.png"
              alt="Avatar"
              style="width: 300px; height: 300px"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="flip-card-back2">
            <h1>John Doe</h1>
            <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
            <p>We love that guy</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only thing you need to change is the width and height of the cards. You need to add some relative values. (I marked the lines where you need to change the values)

```css
.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 25vw; //change here
  height: 25vw; //change here
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
.flip-card2 {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 25vw; //change here
  height: 25vw; //change here
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.flip-card2:hover .flip-card-inner2 {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front2, .flip-card-back2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front2 {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-card-back2 {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

Comment: I can't get it work. I need to have evenly space around them and when I make the screen smaller, they don't go under each other

Answer (score 0):

As the answer above. I think you should have have some custom Css with break points too.
In that case your card will not change the width size value, only go one line down
See example below:

```css
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #pricing {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .product {
    max-width: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```